# Building a simple web app with database?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm building a simple airline reservation system (web app) for a class. I'm trying to find out where to start learning about implementing and integrating a sql database. User's should be able to search for available flights based on destination and departure cities and the like. A good example would be Google Flights. I'd like to access a data base with all of the flight information and display it within tables on the web page. Admins should be able to modify the databases as well.

I've tried to learn about things like Node.js, PHP, and AJAX, but most of the tutorials that I've found have been difficult to understand. Any suggestions would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Given the scope of this question, it might be worth migrating it over to programmers.stackexchange.com? Just a thought

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I didn't know about programmers.stackexchage.com.

Comment: It's relatively new! Just take care when posing questions there  - the community is fairly sensitive. Pose a direct question and be as specific as you can. Maybe read the instructions before posting too. Post a link back here once you've posted.

Comment: This will be closed on Programmers.SE very soon since it somehow manages to e off topic in every possible way there.

Comment: @thorstenmüller this is sadly true. That's why I suggested he read the tips before posting ;)